# Saving UIImage to iOS documents file not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

I'm making an app where you have the option to choose a profile pic from your camera roll. However, once I choose a photo in the collection view when the app is running, the code fails with the common "unexpectedly found nil" error.

The main problem is that after the photo is chosen, I'm trying to save the image data to a file in the documents directory and save the path of that file in UserDefaults so I can always load it back next time the app is used. But when I try to get it back it doesn't work. Here is my method to prepare for segue back to the main view:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? Info
        else { fatalError("unexpected view controller for segue") }
    guard let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell else { fatalError("unexpected sender") }

    if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
        let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)

        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { image, _ in
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)
            let relativePath = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).jpg"
            let path = self.documentsPathForFileName(name: relativePath)
            do {
                try imageData?.write(to: URL(string: path)!)
            } catch {
                fatalError("could not save image to file")
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(relativePath, forKey: "path")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        })
    }
}
```

Here's the documentsPathForFilename() method:

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true);
    let path = paths[0]
    let fullPath = path.appending("/\(name)")

    return fullPath
}
```

When I tested it to see what path the second method gave me it returned:

```
/Users/jamesmcgivern/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5BA257D-1629-4504-918A-1F9BB52C7126/data/Containers/Data/Application/2137260E-8DD8-4992-8007-0FCA9BB52B42/Documents/image_520462970.678922.jpg
```

But I'm only saving the FILE NAME in UserDefaults. That way if the path to the documents directory changes in between runs, I can just get the new path in my other class and append the filename to get the full path and retrieve the image. Now this other code, which is in the viewDidLoad() of another class, is where I get the error:

```
var profilePic:UIImage?

    let possibleOldImagePath = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "path") as! String?
    if let oldImagePath = possibleOldImagePath {
        let oldFullPath = self.documentsPathForFileName(name: oldImagePath)
        let oldImageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: oldFullPath)
        // here is your saved image:
        profilePic = UIImage(data: oldImageData! as Data)!
    }
    if let pic = profilePic {
        self.profilePic.image = pic
    }
```

The documentsPathForFilename method for that class is the same.

Any help in eliminating this error will be greatly appreciated as I have been working on it for a long time.

Comment: @rmaddy This is not a duplicate because I'm already using the solution suggested in that other question